# Secp256k1 Curve Signature close to expected signature but missing 2 segements

Tags: encryption, publish-subscribe, bitcoin, signature, ecdsa

Private Key:

> 7a01628988d23fae697fa05fcdae5a82fe4f749aa9f24d35d23f81bee917dfc3

Message:

> 695369676e65645468697344617461546861744973323536426974734c6f6e67

Result:

> 205587dfc87c3227ad37b021c08c873ca4b1faada1a83f666d483711edb2f4f743
>   04ee40d9fe8dd03e6d42bfc7d0e53f75286125a591ed14b39265978ebf3eea36

Expected Result:

> 304402205587dfc87c3227ad37b021c08c873ca4b1faada1a83f666d483711edb2f4f7430220
>   04ee40d9fe8dd03e6d42bfc7d0e53f75286125a591ed14b39265978ebf3eea36

As you can see the expect result has 2 segments my result did not have:

**304402** 205587dfc87c3227ad37b021c08c873ca4b1faada1a83f666d483711edb2f4f743 **0220**    04ee40d9fe8dd03e6d42bfc7d0e53f75286125a591ed14b39265978ebf3eea36

What am I missing here, is there some compression or something happening to my result.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you got the result you have, but the expected result looks like a standard [ECDSA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) signature in [ASN.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Example_encoded_in_DER)/[DER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.690#DER_encoding) encoding.

To break it down:

- **`30`:** indicates that an ASN.1 `SEQUENCE` will follow
- **`44`:** the length of the sequence, in this case 68 bytes
- **`02`:** indicates that an ASN.1 `INTEGER` will follow
- **`20`:** indicates the length of the integer, in this case 32 bytes
- **`55 ... 43`**: the 32 bytes of the signature's **`r`** value
- **`02`:** indicates that an ASN.1 `INTEGER` will follow
- **`20`:** indicates the length of the integer, in this case 32 bytes
- **`04 ... 36`:** the 32 bytes of the signature's **`s`** value

As I said, I'm not sure what type of encoding is being used for the result that you currently have. It seems to contain the bare minimum information needed to be able to extract the `r` and `s` values from the byte array, but discards everything else. (I suspect it might be some variant of [PER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_Syntax_Notation_One#Packed_Encoding_Rules) encoding or a custom encoding scheme.)

Particularly interesting is the fact that the length indicator for the `r` integer (`20`) is present in your result. Besides the actual `r` and `s` values, this is the only additional information that is strictly needed to be able to successfully parse the signature. As `r` and `s` might be either 32 or 33 bytes, you need one length indicator to know where `r` ends and `s` begins.

Comment: Hello, I am following this process: https://block.io/api/simple/signing and using this c# library to sign : https://github.com/Chainers/Cryptography.ECDSA

Comment: Probably worth trying another method than `SignCompressedCompact()` then. Or find another library, because the one you're using is very poorly documented.

Comment: I will try and find another library to sign